# Не могу решить задачу на Pуthon

Tags: python

[image: Мой код]

```
HCount = 0
LCount = 0
WithoutHCount = 0
stroke = list()
while "SILENCE" not in stroke:
    if "hate" in stroke:
        HCount += 1
    if "love" in stroke:
        LCount += 1
    if "hate" not in stroke:
        WithoutHCount += 1
    stroke = str(input()).split(" ")
if HCount > WithoutHCount:
    print("To the rain.")
if (HCount <= WithoutHCount) and LCount > HCount:
    print("To the sun.")
else:
    print("Cloudy")
```

Comment: Выводит не правильный ответ, т. е не как в примере

Comment: ну печатай переменные после каждого ввода и смотри, что там происходит

Comment: Пожалуйста дополните свой вопрос примером ввода и некоректным выводом программы.

Comment: У вас из строк образуется список. Из примера входных данных в список попадут слова `hates` и `hate`. Счетчик увеличивается единожды на слове `hate`

Comment: в задаче неточные условия (которые даже не спишешь на неправильный перевод). Слова hates и hate по сути разные, но для задачи считаются одинаковыми.

Comment: Ну а в коде ошибка в то, что даже еще до ввода чего-либо значение WithoutHCount  получается равным 1.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, такой вариант сработает:

```
hate_count = 0
love_count = 0
without_hate_count = 0
stroke = str(input())

while "SILENCE" not in stroke:
    if "hate" in stroke:
        hate_count += 1
    else:
        without_hate_count += 1
    if "love" in stroke:
        love_count += 1
    stroke = str(input())

if hate_count > without_hate_count:
    print("To the rain.")
elif (hate_count <= without_hate_count) and love_count > hate_count:
    print("To the sun.")
else:
    print("Cloudy")
```

Теперь переменная `stroke` принадлежит к типу `str` и принимает первую строку ещё до цикла. Если в строке есть необходимое слово или оно отсутствует, соответствующий счётчик увеличивается. Также я использовал оператор `if elif else` вместо `if if else` для увеличения скорости работы программы. Также поменял имена переменным, чтобы они соответствовали стандарту [PEP-8](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html).

Comment: if elif else использовать неправильно. Строка может содержать одновременно hate и love. ТАм в примере даже есть такая.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает)

Comment: @Эникейщик Спасибо, убрал его в цикле, но при выводе его использование уместно.

Comment: @emil Обратите внимание, в моём коде была ошибка.

Comment: При выводе да. У вас там теперь else относится не к тому if, и в цикле ошибка в имени переменной - left_count, а надо love_count

Comment: @Эникейщик Теперь всё должно работать правильно.